# Find a function under the integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, power-series, improper-integrals

For any non-negative integer $n$ I have the following: $$\int_0^\infty x^n f(x)dx=\int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^na_{kn}x^kg(x)dx$$

So, I can write the system of equations (when $n=0,1,2.\ldots$).

I know the coefficients $a_{kn}$ and $g(x)$.

Is it possible to find exactly or approximately the function $f(x)$?

Thank you.